# best way to create this dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

this is my code :

```
vars_ = {
                'attackUp':attackUp,'defenceUp':defenceUp,'magicUp':magicUp,'attType':attType,'weightDown':weightDown,
                'accAttackSword':accAttackSword,'accAttackSaber':accAttackSaber,'accAttackAx':accAttackAx,
                'accAttackHammer':accAttackHammer,'accAttackSpear':accAttackSpear,'accAttackFight':accAttackFight,
                'accAttackBow':accAttackBow,'accAttackMagicGun':accAttackMagicGun,'accAttackMagic':accAttackMagic,
                'mStrInstrument':mStrInstrument,'mStrCharms':mStrCharms,'accDefencePhy':accDefencePhy,
                'accDefenceMag':accDefenceMag,'accWeight':accWeight,'bookTurn':bookTurn,'bookAttackPhy':bookAttackPhy,
                'bookAttackMag':bookAttackMag,'bookStrInstrument':bookStrInstrument,'bookStrCharms':bookStrCharms,
                'bookDefencePhy':bookDefencePhy,'bookDefenceMag':bookDefenceMag,'bookWeight':bookWeight,'name':name,
                'plvl':plvl,'str':str,'ski':ski,'mag':mag,'spd':spd,'locX':locX,'locY':locY,'wName':wName,
                'wAttack':wAttack,'wDefence':wDefence,'wWeight':wWeight,'wType':wType,'target':target,'title':title,
                'uname':uname,'cUrl':cUrl,'mbCnt':mbCnt
                }
```

oh my god , I spent a lot of time on this work , and maybe have more Variable to be added later ,

any easy way to do this ,

thanks

Comment: Looks good.  What's the problem?  If you want to add anoher variable, you just edit it.  What problem do you have?

Comment: I guess this is how dictionaries are created. If you think there are too many values, try to *refactor*.

Comment: Where do all the variables come from? Arguments to a function? Globals? Somewhere else?

Comment: @Baffe Boyois: I think they came from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385815/the-best-way-to-define-these-variables-using-python

Comment: they are the variables that i define .

Comment: I would stop and consider why you are doing this. I can't help but think its not necessary.  You are pretty much recreating `globals()`.  Type that into your interpretter and see if you still want to do this.

Comment: @jon_darkstar, I would vote that comment up twice if I could.

Comment: the correct way of handling this depends on details not shown. You need to show us where you assign those variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stop and consider why you are doing this. I can't help but think its not necessary.

Even if you decide this is necessary (which i doubt) - You are pretty much recreating `globals()`. Type that into your interpretter and see if you still want to do this.

Organize it further like `senderle` suggested in your other post.  And maybe post a broader question with help for organizing your project.

Comment: oh haha i didnt see it above.  yea i commented at first before i reconsidered and decided it was worth of an answer.  thank you =P

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is reformat that dictionary so there is *one* entry per line:

```
vars_ = {
    'attackUp'  : attackUp,
    'defenceUp' : defenceUp,
    'magicUp'   : magicUp,
    'attType'   : attType,
    'weightDown': weightDown,
    # and so on
}
```

I have also lined up the columns so the whole list reads more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array of variable names and pull them out of the `locals` dictionary.

```
x, y, z = 5, 10, 20
l = locals()
d = {}
for v in ['x', 'y', 'z']:
    d[v] = l[v]
# d = {'y': 10, 'x': 5, 'z': 20}
```

`locals` might work on it's own too if you're just wanting to look it up as a string.

```
attUp = locals()['attackUp']
```

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining how `locals()['attackUp']` is any better than simply `attackUp`, especially since it's slower and will suppress important optimisations in Python.

Comment: I'm assuming he's wanting a way to lookup the variables based on the string version of their names so that he can dynamically call them, using `locals` would allow for that.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @miku - look at how you are using the values and seriously refactor.

For example, a Character has Attributes (physical_attack, physical_defence, magic_attack, magic_defence, weight, speed) and Items; Weapons are Items, Swords and Axes and Spears and Bows are Weapons, a Saber is a Sword. Unarmed is a special default Weapon. Charms are Items, but apparently Books and StringedInstruments are Weapons?? Items have Attributes which are added to a Character's Attributes while equipped. Character also has level, location, target, and an accuracy rating for each weapon type (can a Weapon have an accuracy-modifier?).

If you break it down into a class hierarchy this way, it should be much easier to keep track of what you are doing.